# Was this question wrongfully closed?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

This is the post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15440672/139010

I confess, I am a hasty close-voter. I cast my vote, and *then* engaged in something of a discussion with the OP about why "book recommendation" questions just aren't good fits for SO. Clearly I wasn't alone, as the question is now closed and 1 vote away from deletion.

I do wonder, though: should I have let this one fly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* have let this one fly. There's lots of questions that I could justifiably vote to close, but for various reasons (I'm curious about the answer, it's written well, it's funny), I leave alone.

But, [the Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113759/policy-regarding-questions-on-programming-books-and-the-books-tag/113773#113773) you linked to in a comment on that question, and a dozen others, summarizes SO policy. **No book recommendations.** You got into an <strike>argument</strike> discussion in comments - the OP wanted the question kept open. He felt strongly about it. He wrote well, and in good detail. Doesn't change generally accepted guidelines. Totally cool to leave the question alone, totally justifiable to close it.

Answer (score 3):

No, the question was not wrongfully closed.

I've been guilty of this myself, but it bears repeating here:  There's no need to get into a protracted discussion in the comments. This is the internet, people like to argue here.

Instead of arguing, you can always just leave a short explanation with why you voted to close and link it to the appropriate meta discussion. That way, you can save your keystrokes, and don't have to worry that someone may disagree and argue with you.