# Are "best-practices/best-tools" questions legitimate?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, best-practices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exceptional cases for list questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112327/exceptional-cases-for-list-questions)

There are a lot of questions asking about some kind of subjective things, such as best-practices or best tools. Each such tool/practice has its pros and cons and, therefore, the best one, probably, cannot be chosen. Are those kind of questions legitimate? They seem to be too chatty, open-ended, not to the point. Most probably such best-practices collections can be found on any other programming-related web-site. But for some reason they are on SO too.

Some of such SO questions are closed (which is probably, right). But some of them still opened. Is there any particular reason why they are still not closed?

Several examples:

- [What is your most productive shortcut with Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218390/what-is-your-most-productive-shortcut-with-vim)
- [What is your favorite textmate plugin or bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078573/what-is-your-favorite-textmate-plugin-or-bundle)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625/best-diff-tool
- [Favorite (G)Vim plugins/scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21725/favorite-gvim-plugins-scripts)
- https://superuser.com/questions/39384/best-grep-like-tool

PS. Probably, there is duplicate for this question, but I could not find it. Would be glad if you'll find a relevant duplicate.

Comment: They are list/poll questions. There no exceptional or extenuating circumstances where these questions would be legitimate on the SE network.

Comment: Possible duplicate is just hillarious! 10 downvotes! How could that possibly be? I think this is a good question to be asked. And it has good structure and reasoning. Why on earth would it get 10 downvotes?

Comment: I totally agree that it's a very well presented and structured question, **but** downvotes on Meta work differently from SO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138110/178505

Answer (score 2):

These are legitimately non-constructive, and I vote to close as such.

The examples you gave are not even "best practice" questions, only "give me your opinion on the best x" questions. Certain best practice questions can be constructive. An example would be "which is the best practice, a or b, and why?"