# Can I ask for a book recommendation

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Can I ask for a book recommendation on stackoverflow? 
The problem is that there is no objective answer.

Comment: I think you've answered your own question there.

Comment: Wanted to be sure because there are questions for recommendations about books and other things. So don't get me wrong.

Comment: Just curious - why the down votes?  OP isn't proposing book recs be allowed. He's asking whether it's permissible, doing it in the right place, and has given at least a little thought to why they are probably not.

Comment: @Jaydles People can disagree with the idea of asking for a book recommendation.  It's a signal that we clearly don't want it.  Given that voting (either way) carries two meanings, it means there's four possible attitudes towards the post.  The binary nature of voting doesn't accommodate that well, but it's the best we have (for example, you think the post is well-written, a good post on meta, but disagree with the sentiment, you vote it down).  It's why reputation is tied to main site rep on all of the other SE site metas.

Comment: And btw, **DON'T EVEN THINK OF POSTING A BOOK RECOMMENDATION QUESTION!** Thank you in advance. =)

Comment: @Jolly really I don't know what's your problem but dude you have issues. Who asked you to repeat the valid answer?

Comment: a) respect the emoticon (in other words, there's a smiley) b) we have a long, *LONG*, **LONG** history with book questions.  There was a lot of turmoil around those and it was *very* contentious.  So "dude", if you have an issue with me posting on meta, I'd address it in a different manner.  We're all just trying to help.

Comment: @Jolly sorry that I got you wrong but I did not see the smiley but just a repeat of the answer and excuse me I am new here an trying to obey the rules, so I don't know your history as a senior member but assume the best. So again excuse me for finding your comment non-constructive, but in other words I think we all agree. I can as well delete the question because it might have been a mistaken one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do books & learning sources questions belong?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84033/where-do-books-learning-sources-questions-belong)

Comment: @Jenayah indeed let me flag it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### No.

Look at [books](/questions/tagged/books) tag from Stackoverflow.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/books

> DO NOT EVEN THINK OF ASKING THIS QUESTION. List questions (shopping
>   lists) are not suitable for Stack Overflow and are going to be closed
>   as "Not Constructive" immediately.

Comment: Btw thank you for getting into trouble and explaining. You know I found it really logical before going into stackoverflow and trying to post the question and then tag it or look at the book tag, to just come here and ask it. Thanks again and I won't bother the site here again. Got it how it works. No respect for new but senior persons.

Answer (score 6):

No.

Recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow and pretty much the entire network (barring TeX, where they *have* to be on-topic, i.e. TeX related).

Comment: Thank you both! I chose the one with the less points because both answer had the same content more or less. Thanks for the recommendation on where to continue.

Answer (score -2):

You can* ask book recommendations on Programmers. In general though Amazon is pretty good (better than SE will ever be) at managing and providing lists of useful books.

*Provided you follow the rules set forth on the Programmers meta that are complicated and contradictory.

Comment: Nope!! http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tags/books/info `Do not ask for book recommendations; they come under the same category as "what language should I learn next?" type questions.`

Comment: I don't think they're contradictory.  They say you CAN ask questions about a programming book's content, but that you can't ask for recommendations.