# What should I do since general book recommendations are not allowed?

Tags: discussion, questions, books

I asked a question about [capturing audio sessions from other processes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13107368/80274) and found what I need is not available from the windows API and I may need to end up writing drivers to do what I want to do.

I am hoping to find a book that goes in to depth in to the windows sound-system like [Windows Internals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901.aspx) does for other windows parts (From what I can tell from the chapter headings Windows Internals does not, but I have not bought the book yet. I do not have the money to buy that book and some other book that would be on topic, and the local Library does not carry it).

I don't know if I ***need*** to write a driver, that is why I was hoping to find a book to learn more.

I know book recommendations [are not on topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161515/can-i-ask-for-a-book-recommendation), so what can I ask to to help me find a new resource to learn the windows sound system in depth (deeper than what the [MSDN provides](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370802%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) without asking for a book recommendation?

Comment: Have you considered searching Amazon.com for `Windows Internals`? I can't promise you'll find what you need, but some hits look at least interesting... and some have a decent number of ratings/reviews, as well.

Comment: Related, maybe duplicate: [What Stack Exchange site would address software suggestion questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132890/what-stack-exchange-site-would-address-software-suggestion-questions)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could go to chat where discussions and recommendations are on topic.

Barring that, you'll need to go to another site in which getting a book recommendation is on topic.  SO isn't *intended* to be the only programming related resource on the entire web.

Comment: But... why?????

Comment: @Oded [So that Jeff can continue making new startups.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2013/02/civilized-discourse-construction-kit.html)